# Access virtual host from guest os ( oracle virtual box)

Tags: windows, apache, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualhost

I am using ubuntu 11.10 and have installed different virtual host on different ip like

```
127.0.0.2 www.example.local
127.0.0.3 www.wordpress.local
... etc
```

I want to test these website in IE9, for this i have install windows7 in oracle virtual box and also modified host file of windows7 and add this line **10.0.2.2 localhost** at the end of the file and also create a new bridge adapted.
After all this setup i can access localhost of ubuntu from windows7, but find problem while accessing virtual host of ubuntu. 
Please help me to access these virtual host on windows 7, i have already search google, ubuntu forum and stackoverflow for this but didnt find right answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want the virtual adapters ip, ie. the gateway ip.

Comment: yes.I want to connect virtual host(www.wordpress.local) from windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Just add those lines you have added to Ubuntu's host file to the host file in your Windows 7 VM, replacing `127.0.0.x` with `10.0.2.2` should make your Windows VM connect to your Ubuntu host for requests to those hosts. This should usually sufficient, unless your HTTP server is configured to serve `www.example.local` only for connection to `127.0.0.2` and similar for `www.wordpress.local`.

Comment: i have added "10.0.2.2 www.wordpress.local" in window host file but it is not working, it point to localhost.
In ubuntu www.wordpress.local map to 127.0.0.10

Comment: Could you post the Apache VirtualHost config? The part configuring those virtual host should look like either `<VirtualHost *:80>` or `<VirtualHost 10.0.2.2:80>`.